# Nginx SNI + OCSP stapling not working

Tags: nginx, certificate, sni, ocsp

I recently tried to setup OCSP on one of my nginx servers.
Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work and didn't find a solution so far.

The configuration looks like this:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/mysite.com/combined.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/mysite.com/fullchain.crt;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 15s;
```

The fullchain.crt contains the servers cert, the intermediate and the root cert.

If I check these certs by hand with :

```
openssl ocsp -issuer intermediate.crt -CAfile fullchain.crt -cert cert.crt -url http://tm.symcd.com -no_nonce
```

it returns ok:

```
Response verify OK
cert.crt: good
    This Update: Apr  7 11:26:10 2018 GMT
    Next Update: Apr 14 11:26:10 2018 GMT
```

But checking the server with s_client from elsewhere always returns

```
OCSP response: no response sent
```

even after waiting several minutes and nginx always throws the error:

```
2018/04/09 12:59:06 [error] 9474#9474: OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:Verify error:unable to get issuer certificate) while requesting certificate status, responder: tm.symcd.com
```

The server uses SNI since it delivers multiple sites with different certificates.
Somebody got an idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

In your openssl s_client command, you should try again by adding the SNI option (-servername) : 
`openssl s_client -connect <fqdn>:443 -servername <fqdn> -status -tlsextdebug -tls1_2 ...`

I had the same issue et that worked for me.